# GitHub API で issue を close するには？

Tags: github, api

[GitHub API v3](https://developer.github.com/v3/) を使って issue をクローズする方法はあるでしょうか？　[Issue Events | GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/events/) のページをみると Event を新しく作ればいけそうな感じがするんですが、その方法がわかりませんでした。

あるいは、API 経由でなくても、特定の issue を自動的にクローズする方法があれば教えてください。

よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Github Issues API で、`state` を `closed` に編集（変更）することで、API 経由で issue をクローズ出来るかと思います。

https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#edit-an-issue

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#edit-an-issue

`state`を`close`にして対応できたと思いますが、いかがでしょう。

Comment: タッチの差で回答が被りました…。

https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/events/

こちらのEventについては、issueが`close`されたときにどんなissueが閉じられたかという内容が返ってくるものだと思います。

Comment: なるほど。ありがとうございます。